# Admin Menu at bottom of screen

Tags: 7, users

My admin menu keeps randomly showing up at the bottom of the page. Any ideas why?

[image]

EDIT: I've continued to pay attention to the behavior.. and it appears to only happen when there is a "message" displayed at the top (in the green box).

Comment: Super weird... does it only happen when you are in the admin section?

Comment: I think so.. it's intermittent so it is difficult to test.

Comment: I have seen similar weirdness, but haven't come to any conclusions. I am fairly convinced it is a race condition in the admin menu JS.

Comment: I've continued to pay attention to the behavior.. and it appears to only happen when there is a "message" displayed at the top (in the green box).

Comment: What is the frequency of this phenomenon considering average usage?  I'm curious what happens if you utilize the overlay instead.

Comment: It looks like it is happening every time there is a message displayed in that "message" block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal core 7.16 with Omgea 7x-3.1 theme and loads of modules. Just experienced the similar behavior where admin menu was locked at bottom of the page. Read through this, decided to not touch Skinr and instead:

Home » Administration » Configuration » Administration

Turn of the "Adjust top margin", save, clear cache, turn on "Adjust top margin" AND "Keep menu at top of page" - this solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I think this CSS might take care of the problem:

/* to fix admin menu at bottom of page - http://drupal.org/node/1588158 */

body.contextual-links-region {
   position:static;
}

It seems to be caused by CSS position set to relative for the body element. 
See http://drupal.org/node/1588158#comment-6180760

I had this problem myself, and notice that also, disabling the Skinr UI module - not Skinr itself - fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the quickest and cleaner way to fix this is to edit the views page and set HIDE CONTEXTUAL LINKS to YES.